# Why aren't all isogenies over finite fields isomorphisms?

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I know this is wrong, but I don't know where I'm wrong (though I'm sure it's something stupid):

An isogeny between two elliptic curves defined over a finite field is a surjective homomorphism between their groups. Tate's Isogeny Theorem in this case tells us that the numbers of points on the two groups are equal (and, thus, the two groups have the same order). But, being finite, surjectivity implies injectivity. Thus, the homomorphism should always be an isomorphism.

Is my error that the homomorphism is surjective only for the curves defined over the *closure* of the fields (which aren't finite)?

Comment: The two groups have the same order, true… but there’s no reason why the map has to be surjective. It could be that some points in the target elliptic curve only come from points of the domain curve defined on a bigger field. In general, if you have one $2$-torsion point $P$ on an elliptic curve $E$ over some finite field, you can always consider the quotient isogeny $E \rightarrow E/\langle P \rangle$.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the definition of “surjective morphism” here. In my very primitive and old-fashioned understanding, the morphism is surjective if on the level of function fields, the associated morphism makes the one field a finite extension of the other. (I leave to others the translation into modern language.) What it means on the practical level is that the inverse image of every point in the codomain is a nonempty set of points in the domain, each possibly defined over an extension field, which are, as a set, stable under Galois.

Comment: The misunderstanding here may be that, indeed, a nonconstant morphism between smooth projective curves over a field $K$ must be surjective... **on the $\bar{K}$ points**. So an isogeny is surjective on the points over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$, but there are infinitely many of these, so you don't have the pidgeon-hole principle. When you look only at the $\mathbb{F}_p$-points, all bets are off.

Comment: @Mindlack, is your example isogeny using the 2-torsion basically the same example as given in the answer by djao? I.e. the isogeny will have degree 2, thus quadratic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An isogeny is surjective over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. It is not necessarily surjective over $\mathbb{F}_p$ itself.

To give a simple example illustrating the issue: the map $f(x) = x^2$ is surjective over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, but it is not surjective over $\mathbb{F}_p$ itself. In fact this example is more or less exactly what is going on in the isogeny setting.

Comment: You should introduce the equation of $E$ and the group $E(k)$ for any field containing $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Thank you! The example helps!